# String combinations with multi-character replacement (yield return alternative re-write for Java)

Tags: java, combinations

There's another Stack Overflow post that was created for an algorithm related to vehicle registration numbers...

> According to the entered license plate (eg. ABC123) and a list of
>   replacement values (eg 1 replaced by I). I need to get all possibles
>   combinations.

The answer by @ArturoMenchaca is perfect for C#, but I'd like it in Java, but given that 'yield' is not available I really can't wrap my head around how to convert it.

How would you translate this code to Java?

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Combinations(string s, Dictionary<char, char> replacements)
{
    return Combinations(s, replacements, 0, string.Empty);
}

private static IEnumerable<string> Combinations(string original, Dictionary<char, char> replacements, int index, string current)
{
    if (index == original.Length) yield return current;
    else
    {
        foreach (var item in Combinations(original, replacements, index + 1, current + original[index]))
            yield return item;

        if (replacements.ContainsKey(original[index]))
            foreach (var item in Combinations(original, replacements, index + 1, current + replacements[original[index]]))
                yield return item;
    }
}
```

You would call then call the method like this..

```
Dictionary<char, char> dict = new Dictionary<char,char>();
dict['1'] = 'I';
dict['3'] = 'B';
dict['A'] = 'H';
dict['O'] = '0';
dict['0'] = 'O';

var combs = Combinations("ABC123", dict);
```

Comment: As long as memory permits, you could replace the return type with `List<string>` and replace each `yield` with a `list.Add()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java doesn't have a feature for iterating values using "push" logic, like the C# `yield return` does.

Java only supports "pull" logic, using [`Enumeration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html), [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html), or [`Spliterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html) *(what [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) uses)*.

If you have the memory for it, you could of course "push" all the combinations into an `ArrayList`, then "pull" values from there. Converting the `yield return` logic into `list.add()` calls is easy, so I'll assume you don't want that.

The Java equivalent of `IEnumerable` is [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html), so you need an `Iterator` implementation.

The code below will do that. It is based on [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46374733/5221149), so please read that answer for an explanation of the overall logic, but basically, your example would be like generating combinations of characters in this jagged array:

`{{'A', 'H'}, {'B'}, {'C'}, {'1', 'I'}, {'2'}, {'3', 'B'}}`

In the code below, that jagged array is the `textChars` array, but instead of using `char[]` it uses a `String`, because a `String` is really just a read-only `char[]`.

```
public static Iterable<String> combinations(String text, String... replacements) {
    Map<Character, String> repl = new HashMap<>();
    for (String r : replacements)
        if (repl.putIfAbsent(r.charAt(0), r) != null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Duplicate replacement: [" + repl.get(r.charAt(0)) + "] vs [" + r + "]");
    String[] textChars = new String[text.length()];
    long count = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < textChars.length; i++) {
        textChars[i] = repl.getOrDefault(text.charAt(i), text.substring(i, i+1));
        count = Math.multiplyExact(count, textChars[i].length());
    }
    long comboCount = count;
    return () -> new Iterator<>() {
        private long combo = 0;
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return (this.combo < comboCount);
        }
        @Override
        public String next() {
            if (this.combo >= comboCount)
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            long c = this.combo++;
            char[] buf = new char[textChars.length];
            for (int i = buf.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                buf[i] = textChars[i].charAt((int) (c % textChars[i].length()));
                c /= textChars[i].length();
            }
            return new String(buf);
        }
    };
}
```

*Test*

```
combinations("ABC123", "1I", "3B", "AH", "O0", "0O").forEach(System.out::println);
```

*Output*

```
ABC123
ABC12B
ABCI23
ABCI2B
HBC123
HBC12B
HBCI23
HBCI2B
```